# How to kill an async child_process in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-async

I want to run a simple shell script from node and do something with the output. However, child_process never seems to exit and I have to control-c my program every time. I've fiddled around with this a bunch and I think the problem is with the callback because when I remove that, the program successfully exits..

```
sys = require('sys')
exec = require('child_process').exec

p = exec "./script.sh", (error, stdout, stderr) ->
  doStuff stdout, ->
    console.log "finished"
```

For those who hate coffeescript:

```
sys = require('sys');
exec = require('child_process').exec;

p = exec("./script.sh", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  return doStuff(stdout, function() {
    return console.log("finished");
  });
});
```

EDIT:

This was quite a pain to isolate the problem. Do stuff is fetching a url and this hang up problem only seems to happen when there is an error. Here's the code I'm working with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee

path = require 'path'
fs = require 'fs'
program = require 'commander'
urllib = require 'url'
async = require 'async'
nedb = require 'nedb'
sys = require 'sys'
exec = require('child_process').exec

db = new nedb()

fetchUrl = (url, callbackErrHtml) ->
  urlBits = urllib.parse(url)
  protolib = (if urlBits.protocol is "https:" then "https" else "http")
  response = (r) ->
    if r.statusCode isnt 200
      callbackErrHtml('status code isnt 200')
    else if not r.headers['content-type']?
      callbackErrHtml('no content type')
    else if r.headers['content-type'].indexOf('html') is -1
      callbackErrHtml('no html')
    else
      html = ''
      r.on 'data', (chunk) -> html += chunk
      r.on 'end', ->
        callbackErrHtml(null, html)

  httpError = (err) ->
    callbackErrHtml(err)

  require(protolib).get(url, response).on('error', httpError)


indexUrls = (urls, callbackDone) ->
  errorUrls = []

  fetchEach = (url, callbackFetch) ->
    console.log url
    db.count {url:url}, (err, count) ->
      if count isnt 0
        console.log "1 - done", url
        callbackFetch()
      else
        fetchUrl url, (err, html) ->
          if err
            console.log "2 - done", url, err
            errorUrls.push(url)
            callbackFetch()
          else
            db.insert {url:url, html:html, createdAt: Date.now()}, (err, doc) ->
              if err
                console.log "3 - done", url
                callbackFetch()
              else
                console.log "4 - done", url
                callbackFetch()


  doneFetching = (err) ->
    if err then console.log err
    callbackDone()

  async.each urls, fetchEach, doneFetching


p = exec "./test1.sh", (err, stdout, stderr) ->
  if err
    console.log err
  else
    bookmarks = stdout.split('\n')[..-2]
    console.log 'bookmarks:', bookmarks

    indexUrls bookmarks, (err) ->
      if err then console.log err
      console.log "finished import safari bookmarks"
```

And here are the two tests. test1.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "http://hackerexperience.com/"
```

and test2.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
http://sandwichvideo.com/
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
http://onethingwell.org/
http://saastr.quora.com/How-to-Figure-Out-Your-Competitors%E2%80%99-Revenues-in-About-70-Seconds
https://maebert.github.io/jrnl/usage.html"
```

When I run with test2.sh, I get these results in the console and the program exits successfully.

```
bookmarks: [ 'http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/',
  'http://sandwichvideo.com/',
  'http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/',
  'http://onethingwell.org/',
  'http://saastr.quora.com/How-to-Figure-Out-Your-Competitors%E2%80%99-Revenues-in-About-70-Seconds',
  'https://maebert.github.io/jrnl/usage.html' ]
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
http://sandwichvideo.com/
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
http://onethingwell.org/
http://saastr.quora.com/How-to-Figure-Out-Your-Competitors%E2%80%99-Revenues-in-About-70-Seconds
https://maebert.github.io/jrnl/usage.html
4 - done http://sandwichvideo.com/
4 - done http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
4 - done http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/
4 - done http://saastr.quora.com/How-to-Figure-Out-Your-Competitors%E2%80%99-Revenues-in-About-70-Seconds
4 - done http://onethingwell.org/
4 - done https://maebert.github.io/jrnl/usage.html
finished import safari bookmarks
```

When I run test1.sh, the url fetch fails with an error. Here's the console log I get and the program remains hung even though `callbackFetch` seems to get called invoking `doneFetching` and then `callbackDone`.

```
bookmarks: [ 'http://hackerexperience.com/' ]
http://hackerexperience.com/
2 - done http://hackerexperience.com/
finished import safari bookmarks
```

I am at a loss. Thanks for the help.

EDIT2:

So I have some more insight here. If I let test1 run long enough, it eventually exits. However, if I let it keep running, it eventually exists. However, I noticed when I change the url to `'http://break.com/'`, and let it keep running, I get this error that the callback happened too many times...

```
bookmarks: [ 'http://break.com/' ]
http://break.com/
2 - done http://break.com/ status code isnt 200
finished import safari bookmarks
2 - done http://break.com/ { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

/Users/chetcorcos/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:30
            if (called) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                              ^
Error: Callback was already called.
  at /Users/chetcorcos/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:30:31
  at /Users/chetcorcos/Projects/bookmarks/test.coffee:53:13
  at ClientRequest.httpError (/Users/chetcorcos/Projects/bookmarks/test.coffee:34:5)
  at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1548:9)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at net.js:441:14
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: Are you seeing the output "finished" followed by the hang, or just a hang without output? It looks to me like doStuff isn't calling its callback. Could you post that function?

Comment: I'm doing an `async.each`. I'm trying to recreate the error with some simpler code.

Comment: Ah I see. Just paste the entire function up there, that's probably easiest.

Comment: it took a while to clean it up and eliminate the unnecessary stuff. but there it is. I still can't figure it out!

Comment: http://hackerexperience.com/ is actually SSL enabled - I'd guess that probably has something to do with it. Try changing it to https:// and see what happens. Your CURL lib might not be following the http -> https redirect.

Comment: I agree. But that shouldn't cause this program to hang up. It seems that the `response` callback is getting called more than once...